# SQL Get rows based on conditions

Tags: sql, select

I'm currently having trouble writing the business logic to get rows from a table with id's and a flag which I have appended to it.

For example,

```
id:  id seq num:    flag:   Date:
A       1             N        ..
A       2             N        ..   
A       3             N
A       4             Y
B       1             N
B       2             Y
B       3             N
C       1             N
C       2             N
```

The end result I'm trying to achieve is that:
 For each unique ID I just want to retrieve one row with the condition for that row being that

If the flag was a "Y" then return that row.

Else return the last "N" row.

Another thing to note is that the 'Y' flag is not always necessarily the last

I've been trying to get a `case` condition using a partition like
       `OVER (PARTITION BY A."ID" ORDER BY A."Seq num")` but so far no luck.

-- EDIT:

From the table, the sample result would be:

```
 id:   id seq num: flag: date:
A          4       Y     ..
B          2       Y     ..
C          2       N     ..
```

Comment: What is the case condition you tried? And have you tried putting the results of the partition in a common table expression so you can use the case on that?

Comment: Can you show us the exact output you would expect from that sample table?  I am having a hard time figuring out what "unique ID" refers to.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added a result

Comment: Result field would be (A, 4, Y, DATE), (B, 2, Y, DATE), (C, 2, N, DATE)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using postgres and the dataset I'm using is quite large so I'm trying not to union results as it'll take a while

Answer (score 3):

Using a window clause is the right idea. You should partition the results by the ID (as you've done), and order them so the `Y` flag rows come first, then all the `N` flag rows in descending date order, and pick the first for each id:

```
SELECT id, id_seq_num, flag, date
FROM   (SELECT id, id_seq_num, flag, date,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                  ORDER BY CASE flag WHEN 'Y' THEN 0 
                                                     ELSE 1 
                                           END ASC,
                                           date ASC) AS rk
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: @Mureinik Sorry for the late question but if 'Y' does appear more than once per id, does it select the first 'Y' that appears or the last 'Y' that appears ordered by date? If it does select the last 'Y' how could you modify to only select the first 'Y'. Thanks

Comment: @Pyrons I edit the `order by` window clause so only the first `Y` is selected.

Comment: @Mureinik This was the workaround I found that worked http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/431ba/9 but it uses unions

Comment: @Mureinik I'm not sure if there is a way to do it in 1 pass instead of using unions. Opinion appreciated

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to take a `UNION` of two queries.  The first query simply selects all `Yes` records, assuming that `Yes` only appears once per `ID` group.  The second query targets only those `ID` having no `Yes` anywhere.  For those records, we use the row number to select the most recent `No` record.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t1."id seq" DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN cte1 t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id
)
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE flag = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM cte2 t2
WHERE t2.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (with quite generic SQL):

```
select t1.*
from Table1 as t1
where t1.id_seq_num = COALESCE( 
    (select max(id_seq_num) from Table1 as T2 where t1.id = t2.id and t2.flag = 'Y') ,
    (select max(id_seq_num) from Table1 as T3 where t1.id = t3.id and t3.flag = 'N') )
```

Available in a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f7f9/6

Comment: Hi @Turophile, how would I write this if Table1 happened to be a long query and I can't use views?

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT id, flag
FROM yourTable